# Need to write recursive function comparing two integers whose digits are stored in arraylists (java)

Tags: java, recursion

I would just use an iteration instead as it's 1000 times easier, but for the sake of this homework question I have to use recursion comparing two integers. Note that each number is stored as an arrayList with each digit as a single element, so: 12345 = [1,2,3,4,5]. At the moment I have this method

```
public boolean isEqual(LargeInt otherLargeInt) {
    if(digitList.size() != otherLargeInt.digitList.size()
       return false;
```

So if the sizes of the two arrayLists or "numbers" don't match then they're obviously not equal. what I'm trying to do is compare each digit of each number recursively. From my understanding, I can exit the recursive method as soon as one of the digits don't match. Could someone nudge me in the right direction? I'm not sure how to approach this type of question.

Comment: Add the language tag, Java?

Comment: Perhaps they want you to think of it like this: say you have the number a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and b = [ ... ]. They're equal if a[0] == b[0], and a[1] to a[4] = b[1] to b[4]. And a[1..4] equals b[1..4] if a[1] == b[1] and a[2..4] == b[2..4], and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isEqual(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
    if (first.size() != second.size())
        return false;
    else
        // Creating new ArrayLists, so that the contents of the origianl lists remains unchanged
        return isEqualHelper(new ArrayList<Integer>(first), new ArrayList<Integer>(second));
}

public static boolean isEqualHelper(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
    // We have compared all the elements and didn't find any mismatch
    if (first.isEmpty() && second.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else {
        // Found mismatch
        if (first.get(0) != second.get(0))
            return false;
        else {
            // First element of both lists are OK, now check the rest 
            // of the list recursively
            first.remove(0);
            second.remove(0);
            return isEqualHelper(first, second);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Drawback is that this solution modifies the original list arguments

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd want to compare the first digit in each list, if they're equal then recurse, passing in the rest of list (everything but the first element).  At least this is typically what it would look like in a functional language like Lisp, Scheme, Scala, etc.  If you don't have a method to give you the "rest of the list", then you'll have to work with indexes.  Start with 0, pass "index + 1" when recursing.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to recurse it, Like I can only put `return isEqualRec(otherBigInt)` or else I get a type error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compare as below, keep recursing until elements are equal

Call to compare:

```
compare(list1, list2, 0);
```

Recursive Compare

```
boolean compare(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2, int i){
    // if list size reached return true
    if(i == list1.size()){
       return true;
    }
    // else if elements at index are equal call compare(list1, list2, index + 1)
    if(list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))){
        return compare(list1, list2, i+1);
    }        
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```